# *Inline* SVG image scales placed in *file* it does not

Tags: html, css, svg, image-scaling, inline-svg

I have an SVG image that scales beautifully when it is inlined in my HTML, but if I move the very same SVG to a file and try to IMG or OBJECT tag that file in my HTML it simply won't scale.

(I know there are similar questions here but usually the other way around.)

I have read [this](https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/) great article, and others, and I have also read through StackOverflow but still no answers.

BTW I copied the potofgold.svg from [Amazon](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/91525/potofgold.svg) and that behaves perfectly so I guess it must be my particular SVG.

The only thing different that I noticed is my SVG tag looks like: -

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" x="0px" y="0px" viewbox="0 0 250 182.6" style="enable-background:new 0 0 250 182.6;" xml:space="preserve">
```

And the pot of gold is: -

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 60 55" >
```

If I try to trim "redundant" and deprecated options from my SVG tag the browser refuses to display the image. Outdated SVG?

Anything I can do to get the image to scale when it's sourced from a file?

*EDIT 1:*

It's option C [here](https://www.wa.gov.au/organisation/department-of-the-premier-and-cabinet/common-badging) if it helps. Western Australian State Coat of Arms. Is it because it doesn't have a "defs" section?

Further info for @patrick.

I had to un-optimize the SVG so that I could add variables to the colors and an external stylesheet that could be modified by Javascript (if need be): -

```
   <style>
    <![CDATA[<!--<!--
        .st1{fill:var(--coa-bg-color);}
        .st2{fill:var(--coa-bg-color);fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd}
        .st3{fill:none;stroke:var(--coa-bg-color);stroke-width:1.78}
        .st5{fill:none;stroke:var(--coa-bg-color);stroke-width:.45}
        .st6{fill:none;stroke:var(--coa-bg-color);stroke-width:.67}
        .st7{fill:none;stroke:var(--coa-bg-color);stroke-width:.45;stroke-miterlimit:5}
        ]]>
    </style>
```

But regarding height let me once again draw attention to the ridiculously important: -

```
        min-height: 0;
```

On the parent flex container!!!

Anyway here's the functionality Demo I'm working on: -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="application/javascript">
    window.addEventListener("load", () =>
        {
            var imageDOM = document.getElementById("crest").contentDocument;
            var svgRoot = imageDOM.querySelector(':root');
            svgRoot.style.setProperty('--coa-bg-color', '#ffd700');
            
            var crest = imageDOM.getElementById("wa_state_crest");
        });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
:root {
  --main-bg-color: #002f5f;
}
    @-ms-viewport{
        width: device-width;
        height: auto;
    }   
    *, *:before, *:after{
        box-sizing: inherit;
        -webkit-touch-callout: none;
        -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
        -moz-user-select: none;
    }       
    ::-ms-clear{
        display: none;
    }       
    html, body{
        margin: 0px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -khtml-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
        -ms-overflow-style: none;
        -ms-content-zooming: none;
        touch-action: manipulation;
    }
    body {
        background-image: radial-gradient(#fff, #1ecbe1, #ADD8E6);
        overscroll-behavior: none;
        pointer-events: auto;
        display: flex;
        font-size: 14px;
        flex-direction: column;
        height: 100vh;
        padding: 1em;
    }   
    
    .wholeScreen{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        height: 100%;
        min-height: 0px;
    }   

    div#headerDiv{
        display: flex;
        order: 1;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0.5em;
        align-items: center;
        flex-grow: 10;
        flex-shrink: 10;
        flex-basis: 10%'
    }

.field__items {
        display: flex;
        order: 2;
        align-items: center;
        flex-grow: 90;
        flex-shrink: 90;
        flex-basis: 90%;
        min-height: 0;
}
.field__item {
    display: flex;
    order: 3;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    flex-basis: 100%;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    max-height: 100%;
    padding: 3em;
}

#crest {
    animation-name: spin;
    animation-duration: 5000ms;
    animation-iteration-count: 3;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@keyframes spin {
    from {
        transform: rotateY(0deg);
    }

    to {
        transform: rotateY(360deg);
    }
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wholeScreen">
   <div id="headerDiv">
     <h1>Coat of Arms</h1>
   </div>
   <div class="field__items">
        <div class="field__item">
          <object id="crest" title="Government of Western Australia" alt="Western Australian Coat of Arms" data="coa.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Did you try opening your SVG file in *Inkscape* or any other SVG editor and re-save it to a new file? You could also try using [SVG OMG](https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/) or [*svgo* in command line](https://github.com/svg/svgo) to compress and optimize your SVG. It has a big list of options that can alter the *viewBox*, *width* and *height* attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your edit with the link to the concerned page, I had a look at
the page and I notice that the table has different column widths,
leading to different rendering widths of the SVG images.
And effectively, **Option C** seems narrower and therefore the
SVG images scales smaller.

Just playing around with Chrome's inspector and adding these
CSS rules, you'll notice a different rendering:

```css
/*
My idea was: (4 x 22%) + (3 x 4%) = 100%

But it's not correct due to padding and borders, so the browser
will try to correct. So, instead, I'll set the seperating empty
columns to a width of 0% as there's already some padding.

Use !important to override the inline style attributes.
*/

/* Columns containing text and images */
#summary-state-coat-of-arms table td:nth-child(2n+1) {
  width: 22% !important;
}

/* Spacing columns (empty) */
#summary-state-coat-of-arms table td:nth-child(2n) {
  width: 0% !important;
}
```

I didn't try replacing your inlined SVG images by external images.
I just noticed that the problem may be due to the table structure
and not the SVG resizing problem.

Also, I notice that **your "Option C" image in black has a viewBox
height set to 240.85 and the same image in white (for the black
background) has a viewBox height of 182.6, but both have the same
width**. I suggest you should reduce the height of the black one.
This is probably the reason it doesn't center vertically even
if you have `preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"`, which is the
default behavior.

#### Edit, after some comments

Just a question: Are the HTTP headers sending the correct MIME type
for all the SVG images set in the *src* attribute of the `<img>` tags?

It's just an idea, but perhaps this could make some browser have
unwanted behaviours.

Taking your SVG images as there are, formatting/optimizing them in
[SVG OMG](https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/) and then setting
them as `data:image/svg+xml;base64,....` seems to work like expected
on this
[Codepen proof of concept I made](https://codepen.io/patacra/pen/GRwzeMM?editors=1111).

Comment: Thanks for the reply Patrick. I can't see how the points you've raised would lead to Option_3 scaling when inline but not when in a file. Please go to the link I provided and "View Source". Lines 1423 to 1446 containg the SVG in question. Embeded in a DIV it will happily scale to the DIV dimentions. Served up via a file it is static. :-(

Comment: Well, I took your SVG images and converted them to base64 to set them as a data URL in a `<img>` tag. [I put all that on codepen.io to show you the result](https://codepen.io/patacra/pen/GRwzeMM?editors=1111). It's elastic like we want it to be. So, are your HTTP headers sending the correct MIME type for the SVG assets set in the *src* attribute of your `<img>` tags? I had to do this `<script id="..." type="text/x-template">` trick on Codepen because I haven't got a pro account where you can upload assets.

Comment: I can confirm that the conversion to an `<img>`  element should work flawlessly. It is most likely the underlying css, which until now has been geared towards inlined `<svg>`  elements, that needs to be adapted to display `<img>` elements in the same form/layout.

Comment: Patrick's SVG when moved to a x.SVG file also works as desired for IMG tags. Thanks. I still don't know the relevant incantations or how your SVG header attributes can now be whittled down to <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" viewBox="0 0 250 182.6"> but all's well that ends :-)

Comment: Thanks @McMurphy, glad it helped you. I also noticed that the white images over the black background are displaying with a huge height. This is because the images are larger than the cell. You've added a `width: 100%` to shrink them. But you have to add a `height: auto` so that the ratio is respected. It would become `.embedded-entity.embedded-svg.scaled svg { width: 100%; height: auto; }`. Converted to `<img>` tags, you'll probably have to do the same. I often add `!important` in these cases as some wysiwyg editors tend to add the `width`, `height` or `style` attributes to the image.

Comment: Here's the result https://richardmaher.github.io/ScaleIt/test_svg.html

Comment: @McMurphy great for the result! Is there a reason to have some CSS in the SVG itself and another `coa.css` file loaded with `<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="coa.css" ?>`? I imagine it's because `coa.css` is used in several SVG images or that you want it to be easy to do color changes. The disadvantage is that the browser has to do a request just for that. By the way, I always thought that [external CSS was loaded via a `<link>` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/SVG_and_CSS). Is there an advantage/difference when it's loaded via `<?xml-stylesheet ...>`?

Comment: Didn't know that the link tag was available in SVG. I would've used that. When I search for External CSS the XML example was all I found. Yes multiple SVG images for the same CSS would be the most likely reason for an external style sheet. Another reason is it exposes the CSS to Javascript runtime manipulation. A bit more limited in its application.